# how to handle selection form with input text in php mysql to be saved

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm trying to save the value in the text input field to be saved in database.

What I'm trying to do is If I choose singing the singing will be saved and same with dancing If I choose Other in the selection the input will show and I'll be entering the value of other and that value I entered in the input text will be saved in the database.

The problem with my code is If I choose other and put a value in the text, the data value will be saved is only **other**.

#### form

```
Talent:
    <form method=post action=test2.php>
    <select name="talent" onchange="if( this.value=='other' )   { this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible' }else     { this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden' };" required/>
    <option value="Dancing">Dancing</option>
    <option value="Singing">Singing</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    <input type="text" name="other" style="visibility:hidden;" />
    </select>
    <button type=submit>
</form>
```

#### Test2.php

```
$sql="INSERT INTO database (Talent) VALUES('$_POST[Talent]',)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're input field saves the value in $_POST['other']. So you need to check, if other is selected and then insert the input field.
So you're final solution will be:

```
if($_POST['talent'] == "other"])
    $talent = $_POST['other'];
else
    $talent = $_POST['talent'];

$sql="INSERT INTO database (Talent) VALUES('$talent',)";
```

**Hint** Never directly insert POST-values in your database. It's a big risk. For further informations read here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/407379/How-to-Protect-from-SQL-Injection-in-PhP-based-web
Still you also need to escape it. Just read what you can do ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting $_POST[Talent] in database.
So if you select 'Other' option in dropdown,then instead of text box value,'Other' value will be inserted in db.

Try this

```
if($_POST['Talent'] == 'other'])
{
    $other = $_POST['other'];//considering 'other' as name of your rextbox
    $sql="INSERT INTO database (Talent) VALUES('$other',)";
}
else
{
$sql="INSERT INTO database (Talent) VALUES('$_POST['Talent']',)";
}
```

Comment: if I did that those who choose singing and dancing won't be saved in the database.

Comment: it will be saved in db,as we are using isset($_POST['other']).

Comment: if dancing or singing is selected the data saved is blank(nothing)

Comment: then use if condition as answered by Mainz007. Check my edited answer